# Create a frequency chart in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I am trying to create "frequency chart" in Numbers, and found this this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3437599?answerId=16534196022#16534196022) but I don't understand the suggested formula:

```
=INDEX(FREQUENCY(Data :: A, A), ROW()-1)
```

Why the double colons and what is A, A referring to? And where is this formula supposed to go? I don't understand how it goes from the data table to the summary table using a(ny) formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example given, `Data :: A` refers to the very first column on the left, named **DataValues**, from the **Data** table.

Meanwhile, the second `A` pertains to the column called **Intervals** in the **Summary** table.

More info about the use of double colon [Numbers User Guide for Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/calculate-values-using-data-in-table-cells-tan727173a8/mac) :

> **Refer to cells in formulas**
>
> [...] Note that the table name and cell reference are separated by a double colon (::). When you select a cell in another table for a formula, the name of the table is automatically included.

The formula goes into the second column **Frequency** of the second table named **Summary**

[image]

Here is a screenshot took from Numbers so you can see where is the formula and its references. From the given example `Data :: A` would be `A` in the following screenshot and `A`from the example would be `Invervals`on the screenshot.
[image]

You can select the interval dynamically dragging the cursor from the starting to ending cell or by typing the references by hand (for example `$A2:$A25`).